# collecting multiple data from multiple requests into one item in scrapy

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

basically I have a website that contains clothing items. I am starting my spider where I have all the items and I am looping over them one by one, and entering the item by taking the url and accessing the page of it. then, I am trying to get the values of the images (.jpeg url files) and returning them ( each item has multiple colors so I am trying to take all the images of all the colors of this specific item ). the problem is my code right now returns the url of the colors on each line. what I want to do is return all the colors urls of the specific item inside 1 line of the json file and then loop to the next item.

my current code:

```
import scrapy

class USSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'US'
    start_urls = ['https://tr.uspoloassn.com/sadece-online-erkek/?attributes_filterable_product_base_type=T-Shirt']

    def parse(self, response):
        for j in range(int(response.css('.js-product-list-load').xpath("@page").extract_first()) , int(response.css('.js-product-list-load').xpath("@numpages").extract_first())):
            l = 'https://tr.uspoloassn.com/sadece-online-erkek/?attributes_filterable_product_base_type=T-Shirt' + '&page=' + str(j)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=l, callback=self.parse2)

    def parse2(self,response):
        for i in range(len(response.css('a.js-product-images-wrapper'))):
            link = 'https://tr.uspoloassn.com' + response.css('a.js-product-images-wrapper')[i].attrib['href']
            Url = response.urljoin(link)
            yield scrapy.Request(Url, callback=self.parse3)

    def parse3(self,response):
            colors = list(set(response.xpath('//*[@class="js-variant-area "]').css('ul li').xpath("//a[@class='js-variant ']").xpath(
                "@data-value").extract()))
            link = response.url
            arnold = []
            for i in colors:
                 if i[0].lower() == 'v':
                     url = link + '?integration_color=' + i
                     yield scrapy.Request(url,callback=self.parseImage)

    def parseImage(self, response):
        yield{
            'image links': response.css("a.js-product-thumbnail").xpath("@data-image").extract()
        }
```